# What's the difference between red and blue user cards?

Tags: discussion, user-card

I've been looking at a few comments/edits/posts on SO, and I've noticed color differences in the names on their cards.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is this intended?

Comment: Looks like the styling differences of Stack Overflow main site vs Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure that all screenshots are from the SO main site? Red looks more like meta.

Comment: Oh, wow. Mistake on my part. Do you mind answering this question so I could accept that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main site and meta have two different designs. On the main site, the blue design is shown:

[image]

and on meta the red design is shown:

[image]

Comment: More importantly, it has nothing to do with the diamonds. It's just the link color for the design.

Comment: @animuson Thanks. I changed my question in a way that won't invalidate this answer.

Comment: @JL2210 BTW, the diamonds show that the person is a moderator

Comment: @VFDan I know. I just wanted to make the question more general so it could be useful for other people.